# Javascript: Dynamic code via innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, dom

I did a test:

```
<script>
function go() {
    var a = "{tester.string1}";
    alert(a);
}

function change() {
    document.documentElement.innerHTML = document.documentElement.innerHTML.replace(/\{tester\.string1\}/, "replaced!");
}
</script>
<input type="button" value="Go" onclick="go();"/>
<input type="button" value="Change" onclick="change();"/>
```

The value of `a` inside `go()` changed after I clicked/called `change()`(in Inspect Elements). However, the actual value appear in `alert()` still shows `{tester.string1}`. Does this mean the browser won't recompile anything after the page is loaded? (So it's static?) Is there any signal or call I can send to the browser (without reload) for this purpose? I'm not asking anything about `eval()`. I just want to clarify the concept.

Comment: You are assigning it once function is being called..

Comment: `document.documentElement.innerHTML` is off the topic here!

Comment: @RayonDabre — What? `innerHTML` is the main feature of the topic here.

Comment: @Quentiin I said I'm not asking anything about `eval()`. I knew `eval()` is a solution for my case. But I'm not heading for **solution**. I just want to clarify(for me and for everyone) that javascript is relatively **static**. I hunger a chance for somebody to correct me. But now seems I lost the chance.